# Can we please have desktop notifications for questions we've participated in?

Tags: feature-request, desktop-notifications

How about having desktop notifications enabled for the questions I've asked or participated in? The notifications which set in the header panel will be directly available on my desktop similar to a mail account.

Many times users will not be able to keep coming back on the website; hence, these subtle notifications will help users to stay connected and will serve as a reminder of activities.

However, to avoid user discomfort, this capability should be a preference setting.

Comment: And yes, it had *definitely* better be a preference. Notifications roaming free all over my desktop would cause me extreme discomfort.

Comment: What is a "desktop notification"? Like, my computer's desktop? Wouldn't that require some kind of application running on my machine to receive those notifications?

Comment: @CodyGray: I agree that it can be a repeat questions. But is there a solution to this.

Comment: Err, those questions have *answers*. Have you read them?